# Best way to store words for given scenerio

Tags: java, regex, maven, full-text-search, project

I am working on Java project [Maven].

I am confused in one point. I don't know what is logiclaly corect.

**Problem is as follows :-**

Sentence is given, and from their I have extract some particular words.

**Solution that I found**

I make one regex and put in Constants class. Whenever I have to add more words, I simply appended words in regex.

This solves the problem.

**I am confused here**

I am thinking, if I put numbers of text files in resources folder where each text file denotes one regex expression.

**REGEX = (?:A|B|C|D)**

A, B, C, D = Word(String)

Is it a good idea ? If not please suggest any other.

Comment: You need Pattern and Matcher of java.util package.http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html#examples

Comment: @erhun I already used that, and its working fine also. My question is, is it a good way, or I have to make separate file where we can search there.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you save regex's in a text file?  The fact that you're using a regex seems like an implementation detail that you would want to encapsulate (unless you want the significantly greater functionality but also overhead of supporting regexes).

Also, why do you need new files for each word?  That seems like you could just have one file with a word per line that is all of the words you're interested in.  This would be much more simple for a user to understand than 100 files with one regex per file.

Comment: Here file means one generic name, just like, "city". That contains all the city names. Second example, "Animal", that contains all the animal names. Is it better to make a regex or files ?

Answer (score 0):

As my understanding, you want to find some key words from the input string. And those key words could be extened according your requirments.
your current solution is to make this regex `(?:A|B|C|D)` in your Constant class, wheneveer it's required, you'll add more key words in this regex.
If my understanding is not wrong, maybe, one suggestion is to put this regex in your properties file, like this

```
REGEX = (?:city|Animal|plant|student)
```

if too long, it's could be like this

```
REGEX = (?:city|Animal|plant|student|car|computer|clothes|\
        furnature|others)
```

Your second idea, if my understanding is not wrong, is to put the keywords as the file name, and those files are put in one resource folder. therefore, you could obtain those files name to compose the final regexp. If your regex are always fixed as the  `(?:A|B|C|D)` format, then this solution is good & convenient. (Every time, you add one new keyword file, you don't need to modify any source code & property file)